# Why does my debian server freeze?

Tags: debian, server-crashes, debian-stretch

I installed Debian 9 ("Stretch") in a virtual machine hosted on ESXi 6.5
The OS is up-to-date and nothing else has been installed but VMware tools.

Sometimes when I execute a command, the server will freeze and nothing can be done besides resetting the VM (the SSH server becomes unresponsive, all terminals are freezed, it doesn't show a KP or anything else)

I can reproduce the problem very easily: I just have to execute wget a couple of times and the OS will hang.

At first, I thought it could be a RAM problem. I used memtest86+ on the host and no problem was found. I also tried the debian package "memtester" which runs very well in the VM and doesn't make the OS freeze whatsoever.

/var/log/messages shows nothing special, but there's one line I don't understand:

```
Jul  3 13:05:57 myhost kernel: [   58.966715] TCP: ens192: Driver has suspect GRO implementation, TCP performance may be compromised.
```

What could be the problem and how can I debug the whole thing?

Config: 1 CPU / 4 cores - 32GB Ram - 64GB HDD

Comment: Same problem. It is driving me mad.

Answer (score 6):

I had this exact scenario going on. Created a Debian 9 VM under ESXi 6.5 and it would freeze when running a few commands. Also, when I closed an SSH session, it would completely freeze and my only option was to reboot.

I fixed it by changing the network adapter type for this host from the default "VMXNET 3" to "E1000e".

Answer (score 2):

If it is a VM, and you can change some parameters, try to set up another type of network adapter, as that looks network related.

Also, check also the `dmesg` output from time to time, even if it is working ok, as it may show other problems.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://bugs.debian.org/864642) seems related.

Anyway we also have stretch VMs running as guests under VMware, `uname -a` returns:

```
Linux sandbox1 4.9.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2+deb9u2 (2017-06-26) 
x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

but `sudo dmesg|grep ens192` is empty ...

Answer (score 0):

I've had these problems as well and the solution for me was to upgrade the ESXi from 6.5.0-standard (build 4887370) to, in my case, a Dell customized image of version 6.5.0U1 (build 7388607).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and checked the settings. I discovered that VMWare 15 Player defaulted to only giving the VM 512MB of RAM and 1 processor. I increased it to 4GB and 2 processors, and the VM now works with no freezing.